# C# Deserializing a Http POST Response that contains back slashes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to make a POST request to my Web API Backend and retrieve & deserialize the response that I get from it, such that I can access the values returned in the 'User' object sent by the backend. I successfully made a request and got the response.

However the response contains back slashes. I am confused about how this response needs to be deserialized. My code is as follows:

**Here's my POST Request**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MY_SERVER_URL/api/createitem");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
     //'data' is the object that contains the parameters
     string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
     streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     string responseString = result.ToString();
     //responseString contains the response with back slashes
}
```

**This is the response that I get:**

```
{\"$id\":\"1\",\"status\":\"200\",\"description\":\"Status OK\",\"user\":{\"$id\":\"2\",\"Id\":124200,\"Name\":\"Rown Doger\",\"Email\":\"rown@email.com\",\"Password\":123,\"DateJoined\":\"2016-10-28T20:20:50\",\"Picture\":\"\",\"AccessToken\":\"testtoken_3432\"}}
```

How do I deserialize this with C# and retrieve the status, description and user objects separately such that I can access the values inside the user object?

**EDIT**

The Response that comes from the Backend is valid since it gets displayed correctly in Fiddler and Postman.

Comment: You can use Json.Net classes for this purpose. Or copy and paste the response in json2csharp.org and get the classes corresponding json schema.

Comment: That's the issue, when I try it with json2sharp it says 'Parsing your JSON didn't work. Please make sure it's valid.' @mcNets

Comment: Which makes me think that maybe those backslashes are causing the issue

Comment: Maybe you should encode the response string.

Comment: First you should unescape your string if you are going to use json2sharp website, also if this string is correct the response is invalid json ! Your password is specified as int field in the json, but contain characters !

Comment: @mybirthname about the password, my bad.. I just changed the password before posting it on stack. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i accessed [enter link description here](http://json2csharp.com/) , removed all the slash manually and converted it to object

```
public class User
{
    //public string __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Password { get; set; }
    public string DateJoined { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    //public string __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

to Deserialize use JavaScriptSerializer:

```
  string json = "{\"$id\":\"1\",\"status\":\"200\",\"description\":\"Status OK\",\"user\":{\"$id\":\"2\",\"Id\":124200,\"Name\":\"Rown Doger\",\"Email\":\"rown@email.com\",\"Password\":123,\"DateJoined\":\"2016-10-28T20:20:50\",\"Picture\":\"\",\"AccessToken\":\"testtoken_3432\"}}";
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  RootObject Res = js.Deserialize(json, typeof(RootObject)) as RootObject;
```

this will Deserialize, but you have two special character property, that will not be converted, so u have to comment them and run your code.

Comment: According to my code, that would be `responseString = Regex.Unescape(responseString);` right? Sadly that didn't change the response James

Comment: pass responseString  to it and see

Comment: Tried that now James. No change :/

Comment: r u debugging and seeing the result, if yes see in "text visualizer" and see if escape charter is present or not

Comment: while seeing the result u have 3 options on the left corner(one small search icon with a drop down), use text visualizer and see , if slash present.

Comment: OOPS! The Text Visualizer doesn't show the slashes!

Comment: Oh wow yeah the Text Visualizer doesn't show the slashes James. So which means its added by C# right